# MYSQL query to fetch daily, weekly and monthly sales

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax

I am using PHP and I want to fetch data of daily, weekly and monthly sales/transfers from my sales/transfers table. Our month starts at 10th of every month and weekday is from Monday to Friday. But I want to use America/New_York timezone instead of my own. For that, I have done this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$usa_date = date("Y-m-d");
$start_date_of_week = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('monday this week'));
$start_date_of_month = date('Y-m-01 00:00:00');
```

These are the values I intend to fill:
[image: Values on Dashboard]

My transfer table only contain entries for sales/transfers and one entry per transfer.
Following is examply of how my table looks like:

```
id  Date           AgentID      AgentName   Accepted
1   2021-06-16     100          Bevan       No
2   2021-06-16     101          Alice       Yes
3   2021-06-17     102          Jaffer      Yes
4   2021-06-17     101          Alice       No
5   2021-06-18     100          Bevan       Yes
```

I want to retrive data using AJAX and my code is this

```
$.ajax({
    'url': "<?=  base_url(). "/dashboardStats";?>",
    'method': "GET",
    'dataType': "JSON",
    'contentType': 'application/json'
}).done( function(data) {
    $(".dailySales").text(function(i, origText){
        alert (data);
        return "1000";
    });
    })
});
```

**My problem statement is**: If I get data individually for each card, I am able to do it, for example using following code to get daily sales data for all:

```
select count(*) as TotalTransfers from transfers
```

But running so many Ajax request for each box looks so inefficient. **So I want to use as few SQL statements and AJAX requests as I can.** Is there a way where I can get data for more than one card? I know the answer is yes and its possible using Cases in SQL but I need to integrate DATE as well and I am not sure how to do that.
The results should not show data for last 7 or 30 days, but from the start date of week and month of every year to span when user checks it.

I hope I have been more eloborate in my edit now. Please ask if more clearity is needed.

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? It's not clear if you're trying to ask us for the solution to the whole feature (which is too much to ask here) or there is one specific part you are blocked on?

Comment: @ADyson I have expanded my explanation for this question. Please look into it, I want to only know how to integrate date time with SQL select statements to fetch as much data in as few SQL queries.

Comment: Thanks, I've voted to re-open it so that answers can be given. It needs one more vote, I believe